# Correct way to change user table relationship?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an event system that has two tables, EVENTS and EVENT_CREATORS.  I have been linking events to creators by placing creator id in the events table as I thought I would only ever have one event creator.

I now need the ability for more than one creator to edit an event.  Should I add simply add additional fields to EVENTS table, i.e ec_id, ec_id_2, ec_id_3, etc.  Or does it make more sense to add a cross reference table to the database and a separate table for additional creators?

Comment: It depends whether the number of creators is fixed, or variable.  It sounds like it's more likely to be the latter, in which case I'd go with the cross-reference table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is those cases, where it would be wise to use a cross reference table. I will explain it step by step. First

- Create a new table. Call it "event_reference"
- Give the following FIelds: `Id`, `Ref_Id`, `Creator_ID`.

I will omit the need of the EventId, because we are creating a table which is a reference to the event, so event's table will hold the `Ref_Id` to keep in track of all the references.

- *Next*, Modify the `events` table and store `Ref_ID` instead of `Creator`

In such way, you can fetch all the creators of an events in the ***normalized*** way.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 tables:

```
Event (with an ID field)
Creator (with an ID field)
EventCreator (2 fields: eventID and creatorID)
```

This should pretty much cover every possible relationship between events and creators. You can limit the relationships by creating indexes on the EventCreator table.

Answer (score 0):

The simple say is to just add a cross reference table.  This way you don't have to worry about how many creators someone will need in the future.

So, have a table like:

**xref_Events_Creators**
EventId
CreatorId